# Change value in array of each object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, arraylist

I want to change value of single key in array of each object how can i loop in through all entries in array using JavaScript? i am tried to using _.map and inside map using _.each but my was not getting as expected output.

```
{
   "errorMsgs":null,
   "data":[
      {
         "productID":1,
         "productTitle":"'TShirt'",
         "productPrice":120,
         "productComparePrice":12,
         "productThumbImage":12.jpg,
         "status":1
      },
      {
         "productID":2,
         "productTitle":"'Shirt'",
         "productPrice":120,
         "productComparePrice":12,
         "productThumbImage":34.jpg,
         "status":1
      },
      {
         "productID":3,
         "productTitle":"'Pant'",
         "productPrice":120,
         "productComparePrice":12,
         "productThumbImage":23.jpg,
         "status":1
      }
   ]
}
```

My expected output will be on like below:

```
{
   "errorMsgs":null,
   "data":[
      {
         "productID":1,
         "productTitle":"'TShirt'",
         "productPrice":120,
         "productComparePrice":12,
         "productThumbImage": http://localhost:3000/api/12.jpg,
         "status":1
      },
      {
         "productID":2,
         "productTitle":"'Shirt'",
         "productPrice":120,
         "productComparePrice":12,
         "productThumbImage": http://localhost:3000/api/34.jpg,
         "status":1
      },
      {
         "productID":3,
         "productTitle":"'Pant'",
         "productPrice":120,
         "productComparePrice":12,
         "productThumbImage": http://localhost:3000/api/23.jpg,
         "status":1
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You need to show your coding attempt so we can show you what you did wrong and how to fix it. Also, you should be using `.forEach()` if you're doing it for side effects rather than  to return an array of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.map()` method like this:

```js
const obj = {
  "errorMsgs": null,
  "data": [{
      "productID": 1,
      "productThumbImage": '12.jpg',
    },
    {
      "productID": 2,
      "productThumbImage": '34.jpg',
    },
    {
      "productID": 3,
      "productThumbImage": '23.jpg',
    }
  ]
}

const res = obj.data.map(d => ({...d, productThumbImage: `http://localhost:3000/api/${d.productThumbImage}`}));
const newObj = {...obj, data: res}
console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the elements of the `data` property's array value and change their target property. Assuming `obj` holds the object:

```
obj.data.forEach ( ( po_element, pn_idx ) => {
    po_element["productThumbImage"] =
        `http://localhost:3000/api/${po_element["productThumbImage"]}`;
};
```